# Unity Shader Graph - Water shader - Tiling problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I'm trying to create a simple water shader (following a tutorial) using a gradient noise to create a wave effect. The shader works fine, but I'm using multiple square meshes to define a long and thin water strip, and the waves don't tile across the meshes (the "seams" between the meshes have different heights).

I've tried changing the node settings to the world position but it didn't help with the tiling.

I've read somewhere to use a tiling noise texture instead of the generated noise node (which doesn't tile), but replicating the same node structure with a texture instead, won't connect to the final Input. I thought it's because the gradient noise node outputs a float value and the texture outputs a float 3 value,but I've tried using just one channel from the texture or using a combine node and the final node still doesn't accept the connection. Any help on how to connect the node setup or make the shader tile across several meshes is much appreciated. :D
[picture of shader graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIo0i.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.